# Counting without zeroes

Tags: python, performance

Below is a python script that generates the sequence `['a', 'b' .. 'z', 'aa', 'ab' .. 'az', 'ba', 'bb' .. 'zz', 'aaa', 'aab', ..]`

This is essentially counting in base 27, replacing every digit with the n-th letter of the alphabet, but skipping any number that would have a `'0'`.

```
import string


def gen_labels():
    i = 0
    n = len(string.ascii_lowercase) + 1
    while True:
        i += 1
        j = i
        result = ''
        while True:
            c = j % n
            if not c:
                break
            result = string.ascii_lowercase[c-1] + result
            if j < n:
                break
            j = j // n
        if c:
            yield result


print(list(zip(gen_labels(), range(1000))))
```

However, the code seems overly long to me for generating such a straightforward series and it's doing a lot of work to break down values that would have a `'0'` in them in base 27.

What is a more efficient way of generating the exact same (infinite) series?

Note that I'm not worried that much about speed, but mainly about the brevity / simplicity of the algorithm - it seems overly complicated, but I don't really see my way to an efficient realisation.

Comment: What is one of the numbers/letter combinations being skipped?

Comment: @Graipher he probably meant to say that no letter maps to number zero.

Comment: Isn't it more like counting in base 26, with `0` => `a`, `1` => `b`, etc.

Comment: filter out all those with a 0

Comment: @Barmar, actually no. Imagine an alphabet with only [a, b]. The series would be `[a, b, aa, ab, ba, bb, aaa, etc.]` - turn that into numbers and you get `[0, 1, 00, 01, etc.]` so it's not like counting in base 26, with that mapping. Instead, if you count in base 27 `[0, 1, 2 .. p, 10, 11, 12, ..]` and leave out the numbers containing 0, you get `[1, 2 .. p, 11, 12, ..]` and then map using `1` => `a` etc., you get the correct series. That's the whole issue, I just feel there may be a more efficient modelling of the same problem.

Comment: Can you please name a few values that would not be present?

Comment: @shrivaths, if the character set would be [a, b, c] and 1 => a, 2 => b, 3=>c, with 0 missing, the values in the output are [1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33, 111, etc.] - i.e. counting in base 4, skipping values that have zeroes - but see below for a different look at the same problem, looking at the series as a complete product of the character set of with an increasing number of factors.

Comment: @Grismar You're right. With normal numbers, `01` is the same as `1`, but your alphabet sequence doesn't have a zero that works like that.

Comment: Is this [bijective base-26](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration#The_bijective_base-26_system), as used in many spreadsheets ?

Comment: You're right @DavidCary, thanks for putting a name to it - I wasn't aware.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, what you want is just a product of the alphabet, with increasing numbers of elements. You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for this:

```
from itertools import product, count
from string import ascii_lowercase

def generate_labels():
    """Yields labels of the following form:
       a, b, ..., z, aa, ab, ..., zz, aaa, aab, ..., zzz, ...
    """
    for n in count(start=1):
        yield from map("".join, product(*[ascii_lowercase]*n))
```

Here is what it outputs:

```
from itertools import islice

print(list(islice(generate_labels(), 1000)))
# ['a', 'b', ..., 'z', 'aa', 'ab', ..., 'az', 'ba', 'bb', ..., 'bz', ..., 'za', ..., 'zz', 'aaa', 'aab', ..., 'all']
```

This has the slight disadvantage that the list being passed to `product` gets larger every iteration. But already with \$n=5\$ you can generate \$\sum_{k=1}^n 26^k = 12,356,630\$ labels, and the list is only about `sys.getsizeof([ascii_lowercase]*5) + sys.getsizeof(ascii_lowercase) * 5` = 479 bytes large, so in practice this should not be a problem.

---

I also made the name a bit longer (and clearer IMO) and added a [`docstring`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) to briefly describe what the function is doing.

Comment: You're right, it is just a full product with increasing length - exactly the fresh look at the problem I was after, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The question is basically to continuously find the next lexicographically smallest string starting from 'a'

Here's the code I created to solve with recursion:

```py
from sys import setrecursionlimit
setrecursionlimit(10 ** 9)

ALPS = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

def parsed_string(l):
    return ''.join(ALPS[i] for i in l)

def solve(string=None, i=0):
    """
    Prints the next lexicographically smallest string infinitely:
       a, b, ..., z, aa, ab, ..., zz, aaa, ..., zzz, ...
    """

    # Entering a list as default parameter should be avoided in python
    if string is None:
        string = [0]

    # Base case
    if i == len(string):
        print(parsed_string(string))
        return

    # Generate values if the current element is the alphabet
    while string[i] < 26:
        solve(string, i + 1)
        string[i] += 1

    # If the current index is the first element and it has reached 'z'
    if i == 0:
        string = [0] * (len(string) + 1)
        solve(string)

    else:
        string[i] = 0

solve()
```

**EDIT 1:**

- This might cause `MemoryError` or `RecursionError` if the code is run for too long
- You can `yield` the value or `append` it to a list if you wish. The code was to provide a basic idea of how to solve the problem

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's not wrong, but you're right - the recursion is risky, especially when you change parameters and a large number of labels is needed for a small character set (unlike in my original example). @graipher has the better solution in that respect.

Comment: Of course! I agree. We just have to explore new possibilites, right? :D

Answer (score 0):

I thought I might compliment the other answers with an approach that follows the OP intuition closer.

I made it recursive, and factored out the creation of the sequence to a helper function :

```
def nth_label(n,symbols,accumulator=""):
  q = n // len(symbols)
  m = n % len(symbols)
  if q==0:
    return symbols[m]+accumulator
  else:
    return nth_label(q-1,symbols,symbols[m]+accumulator)

def generate_labels():
  i = 0
  while True:
     yield nth_label(i, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
     i += 1
```

Please be aware I just tested the equivalent javascript, not this python version!

Note that though this uses a recursive function, the depth of the recursion is only logarithmic on the number, with the base being the number of symbols (so a small number of recursions in practice).

It's easy to convert it to an iterative function, if a little less elegant IMO. It might be easier to see how this is different from  itertools.product in the explicitly iterative version:

```
def nth_label(n,symbols):
  result = ""
  q = n // len(symbols)
  m = n % len(symbols)
  while q>0:
    result = symbols[m]+result
    n = q - 1
    q = n // len(symbols)
    m = n % len(symbols)

  return symbols[m]+result

def generate_labels():
  i = 0
  while True:
     yield nth_label(i, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
     i += 1
```

It's proportional to log_k of n, where k is the number of symbols, in both space and time.

Sorry for the previous errors, this one [is tested ;)](https://tio.run/##dZDdTsMwDIXv@xRWJKRUK1rGJVL3FNwhhNLOtAHHbfPD6F6@ZOmEJmC5so@T7xxnnEM/8MOyHPANOPSvpBskyZWfbTOQr3TbRhtJh8HVQpSPBYBDHylADUKkbkoFw3YLhCwvr8qk26zf/ZaPvSGEaa/OpCvW5cqzfdmsWh5zmkxwD7vc3bK6YZajhuj4H3hx3rdDRqcDrkt7mbczCaV@gj65iGtSmA3S4eqPTAVCN20Cdb15/yDLwzg5H@Ln8Ws@iTVYwm3qFL8YneEgyfggT2aUf6wrcJo7lDulVJnOsnwD)

Comment: Yeah, it basically codes out what @Graipher also provided as a solution; your recursive solution takes the place of the `itertools.product` and your `generate_labels` routine is the outer loop increasing the count. Thanks for contributing though, it may provide some additional insight to people that aren't familiar with those Python library functions. I updated your code to follow Python naming conventions and fixed a bug in the 2nd line of your `nth_label` function and tested the code - it works.

Comment: @Grismar Not exactly, though. The `nthLabel` function doesn't take a concatenation of the symbols, just a single copy. If I read his code correctly, he passes a list that gets bigger on each iteration? My code does what you did as close as possible, I just simplified the part that looked overly complex to you originally.

Comment: @Grimar PS: your edit was rejected by the review queue, I'll change those names, not much of a pythonista myself sorry

Comment: @Grismar I've updated the answer, to make it more obvious how this differs from `itertools.product`.